# Selenium webdriver : Multiple drivers

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have used 3 drivers firefox, chrome and IE for automated testing.

```
static WebDriver driver ;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            runTest(driver, "FireFox");

            //Chrome
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/selinium_drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            runTest(driver, "Chrome");

            //IE
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E:/selinium_drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            runTest(driver, "IE");
            }
```

The problem is the second driver is starting before the first driver complete it's process. How can i stop second driver till the first driver finish it work.

```
public static void runTest(WebDriver driver, String browserName) {
        try {
            testLogin(driver);
            testSignupC(driver);
            testSignUpCLogin(driver);
            driver.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //log stack trace
            //Alter(test failed in browser name)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the browser close with `driver.quit()`? Which version of webdriver jar are you using?

Comment: driver.close(), version 2.48.2

Answer (score 4):

You didn't mention your WebDriver version; my comments are based on API 2.45.

First, you should call `driver.quit()` instead of `close()`:

```
/**
 * Close the current window, quitting the browser if it's the last window currently open.
 */
void close();

/**
 * Quits this driver, closing every associated window.
 */
void quit();
```

Second, you should secure the driver shutdown in a finally block:

```
try {
    testLogin(driver);
    testSignupC(driver);
    testSignUpCLogin(driver);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    //log stack trace
    //Alter(test failed in browser name)
} finally {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Additionally, I would surround `quit()` with a try/catch on `WebDriverException` and set driver to `null` in order to prevent its reuse since the driver initialization (`startClient()`, `startSession()`...) is done in the constructor:

```
} finally {
    try {
        driver.quit();
    catch (WebDriverException e) {
        // log if useful else NO OP
    }
    driver = null;
}
```